# How to close an std::ofstream that has been passed by const reference through a thread to a function that takes an std::ostream const&?

Tags: c++, multithreading, fstream

I have a (set) of function(s) that take in an **std::ostream&** so that I can change where they will output. These are passed into a control function that runs them at a certain time each day, and each instance of control function runs and is instantiated in it's own **std::thread**. In order to pass an **std::ofstream** to the inner worker functions, they must be passed as a **(stream typename) const&** (this is the only way possible with threads but I don't remember exactly why). Because I did not want to implement the code that converts the **std::ostream const&** back to a useable reference within the function, I also created yet another wrapper function that does this and then passes the necessary parameters to the worker functions.

> The control function

```
//"DayTime" is a struct containing the target time of day
template<typename returntype, typename... args>
void routineThread(std::atomic_bool const& control, const DayTime tme, const time_t updateinterval, returntype(*func)(args...), args... arg) {
    std::atomic_bool& con = const_cast<std::atomic_bool&>(control);
    while (con) {
        //check if control bool has updated every update interval
        //"d_untilNext" returns the number of seconds until the target time of day
        while (updateinterval < d_untilNext(tme)) {
            if (!con) {
                break;
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(updateinterval));
        }
        if (con) {
            //"d_nextTime" returns an "std::chrono::time_point" for the target time of day
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(d_nextTime(tme));
            func(arg...);
            //wait until target TOD has passed, otherwise the function will be run multiple times
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

> The stream converter and "templatefunc"

```
typedef void(*templatefunc)(const char*, std::ostream&);

void streamWrapper(const char* message, std::ostream const& output, templatefunc func) {
    std::ostream& out = const_cast<std::ostream&>(output);
    if (typeid(output) == typeid(std::ofstream)) {
        std::ofstream fout;
        fout.basic_ios<char>::rdbuf(out.rdbuf());
        func(message, fout);
        fout.close();
    }
    else {
        func(message, out);
    }
}
```

> An example worker function

```
void work(const char* message, std::ostream& output) {
    output << dateStamp() << ": work done?" << newline; //dateStamp() -> returns string with date and time
}
```

> An example std::thread implementation

```
std::atomic_bool run = { true }; //this value is manipulated elsewhere

std::thread th(routineThread < void, const char*, std::ostream const&, templatefunc > , std::ref(run), streamWrapper, "message", std::fstream("/data/logs/work.txt", std::ios::trunc), work);
```

My problem is that when an **std::fstream** parameter is supplied (into the thread constructor, which passes it to the control function, which then passes it to the stream wrapper function), the constructor opens the file I am trying to log to and stays open until the end of the thread is ended. Since the stream has been passed to an **std::ostream&** parameter, I cannot close or manipulate the original object at all, and the file stays open within that object until the thread ends (the end of the program), thus any output that the inner worker functions have submitted is either not written to the file or is only written when the thread is ending and the original fstream object is deleted. This makes for some pretty useless logging, as the program is meant to run continuously (although it is occasionally restarted). Is there is anything that I could change to allow the original stream to be closed, while retaining the flexibility of an **std::ostream&** parameter? Again, the goal is to log to a file and for the output to be visible immediately, instead of appearing only when the program ends. I know that I could just change the parameter to only take an **std::ofstream&**, but I only want to do this if it is the only option.

Comment: Sorry, it is not possible to do this (correctly and safely) for two separate fundamental reasons. But they all boil down to the same basic fact that C++ simply doesn't work this way.

Comment: You should resolve `[In order to pass an std::ofstream to the inner worker functions, they must be passed as a (stream typename) const& (this is the only way possible with threads but I don't remember exactly why).]` instead of this question. Most of time `const_cast()` should not be used. It smells bad in your use case.

Comment: Well thanks guys. As far as resolving the const& part, there was another stackoverflow question that I found about that, but after scrolling through my browser history a few times I couldn't find it. Ill just have to use a more direct form of references.

Comment: Can’t you take the `ostream` by value or rvalue reference?